# Spring Websocket - determine if user is connected

Tags: java, spring, websocket, client-server

I'm using Spring Boot for building REST API. Part of site uses WebSocket for client-server communication for creating "rooms" for two users. The rooms need to be ordered via API for a specific time and duration e.g. 21-12-2016 11:00 for 1 hour. In webapp I'm setting timeout from now, to ordered time for showing popup with buton "Join a room". When user click this button, then room is created. But I need to make button disabled when the second user is offline.

How can I determine if user is online in Spring WebSockets?

My solution is to listen SessionConnectEvent and SessionDisconnectEvent, and update user status (in database) as online or offline. It works only when user has only one websocket connection. Because if he has e.g. 2 tabs open on the same page, then 2 connection are established (status = online). When user close one tab, then disconnect event is fired and status is changed to offline, while he is online (still 1 tab opened).
SessionDisconnectEvent.

Fix for this solution is to save in database pair session_id and user_id on SessionConnectEvent and remove it on SessionDisconnectEvent.

Is there a better way to determine if user is online?

Answer (score 0):

Let me tell you my approach,
I enabled Spring Security so that a Principal (with its .getName()) is associated to the session. Then using the simple broker, added the listeners you mentioned (SessionConnectedEvent and SessionDisconnectEvent) and the following simple class.

```
@Component
public class SessionManagement {
    private final Map<String, Boolean> sessions = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public boolean isConnected(@NonNull String userId) {
        return this.sessions.getOrDefault(userId, false);
    }

    public void connect(@NonNull String userId) {
        this.sessions.put(userId, true);
    }

    public void disconnect(@NonNull String userId) {
        this.sessions.remove(userId);
    }
}
```

Listeners will be something like:

```
@Component
public class WebSocketConnectedListener implements ApplicationListener<SessionConnectedEvent> {
    private final SessionManagement sessionManagement;

    @Autowired
    public WebSocketConnectedListener(SessionManagement sessionManagement) {
        this.sessionManagement = sessionManagement;
    }

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(SessionConnectedEvent event) {
        this.sessionManagement.connect(Objects.requireNonNull(event.getUser()).getName());
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.